# How to get list of all symbols in fred database?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to query every single series in the fred database using r. I have checked out both the quantmod and fImport packages, and they work fine, though it seems that quantmod fits my use a bit better.

The only problem is that the query function in both packages takes as an input the name or names of the symbols you want, and doesn't have any funciton for "query all data" or even "query all data of a certain type". I was hoping at least that there would be some comprehensive list of all symbols in FRED, but I have googled and searched all over, and there isn't even a mention of this.

I realize this use case may sound a bit strange, and unfortunately I can't explain the  reason for it for proffesional reasons.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Best,

Paul

Comment: Paul - were you able to achieve the result of compiling a comprehensive list of FRED series IDs?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember this very well. but I think what I ended up doing is using a pre-purchased data set from fred that my company had. it may not have had every symbol, but it had a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check whether this has what you are looking for:
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories

Each category is available for bulk download.

Comment: This appears more like a comment.

Comment: Well, I believe this does answer his question ...

Comment: actually it does! thank you. I will have to write a script to iterate through all of the dirtectories in this zip file and then use that to compile a list/ single data frame containing all of the data. once I do I will upload a list of names herke just for fun!

Comment: Updated the link

Answer (score 2):

The following answers the initial question:

To get a comprehensive list of all data series on FRED you can leverage the [FRED API](https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/), and in particular the following calls:

- /category
- /category/children
- /category/series

You can start with the root category (id = 0) and traverse the category tree for the metadata including the series symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You might find Quandl useful, where amoung other sources you'll also find FRED:

- https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED?page=13

Rotating the `page=13` counter in the URL, you will eventually donwload names of all datasets (you'll need to download all pages and parse them a bit).